# Java 8 & Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, java-8, equinox

I have using Eclipse Luna win32.x86_64 runing with Java 8.

Here from the `Help Menu > About > Installation Detail > Configuration Tab`:

```
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_05-b13
java.version=1.8.0_05
```

I have created new plug-in project, requesting `JavaSE-1.8` as Execution Environment:

[image: Plug-in Editor. JavaSE-1.8 as Execution Environment]

In the `myplugin/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file I have of course:

```
 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

I use this plugin in a product file. When I try to validate it, I get following error:

[image: Validations Dialog, opened from the product file editor]

Of course if I start the product, I get:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-10 08:14:22.042
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-07-10 08:14:22.043
!MESSAGE Bundle update@********/myplugin/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 myplugin 2 0 2014-07-10 08:14:22.044
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
```

---

I have tried to verify a lot:

**Preferences > Java > Installed JREs**

[image: Installed JREs]

**Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Excution Environments**

[image: Excution Environments]

**Preferences > Java > Compiler: JDK Compliance Compiler compliance level**

[image: Compiler]

When I start the product, I checked in the *Launching* tab that I use the jre8 as execution environment.

I have even tried to change the `Java Runtime Environment` in the `Run Configurations` Dialog:

[image: Java Runtime Environment]

I have tried different settings. None of them works.

---

What is wrong?

Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error means that your bundle has a `Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"` entry in its manifest. So this means the bundle will only start when there is a bundle that provides this capability.

In case of the osgi.ee capability it is the OSGi framework (equinox) that should provide this capability. Apparently it does not do this.

So one approach would be to remove the header from you bundle Manifest.
The other would be to make equinox export the capability. Perhaps you could simply try with the newest equinox version. Not sure if this helps though.
You could also try to set the framework property (using -D):
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE";version:List="1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8"

See

- [The same problem on the eclipse list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/equinox-dev/msg07453.html)

Comment: Thank you... You are right I have an old Juno Equinox in my target platform.

Comment: I have Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200 and this error still appears. What worked was what Christian mentioned as a first option: open META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and under "Execution Environments" remove JavaSE-1.8 or replace it with JavaSE-1.7 and after I exported ("hello world") application it started without problems.

Comment: I have this issue with Java10. Where can the framework poperty be set? Somewhere in the run configuraiton for the Eclipse Application?

Answer (score 19):

Sharing my experience on retrofitting a target platform based on Juno 3.8.2 to run JUnit plugin tests with `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` ("BREE") **`JavaSE-1.8`**:

#### Failed approach 1: Fragment

Creating a fragment to `org.eclipse.osgi` with a `Provide-Capability` header in the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: FrwJava8Support
Bundle-SymbolicName: frwJava8Support
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.8.2"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Provide-Capability: osgi.ee;osgi.ee="JavaSE";version:List="1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8"
```

This capability was never picked up.

#### Failed approach 2: Startup parameter

Using `-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.capabilities` as outlined in Christian's answer.

First of all, the argument must be quoted correctly:

```
-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.capabilities="osgi.ee; osgi.ee=\"JavaSE\";version:List=\"1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8\""
```

This approach might have worked for any other use case other than `pde.junit`. I still got this (slightly different) exception:

```
!MESSAGE Bundle com.XXX.tst.frw.common_1.0.0.qualifier [92] was not   resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.XXX.tst.frw.common 2 0 2015-04-18 13:43:55.336
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-04-18 13:43:55.336
!MESSAGE Bundle com.XXX.tst.frw.common.test_1.0.0.qualifier [101] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.XXX.tst.frw.common.test 2 0 2015-04-18 13:43:55.336
!MESSAGE Missing host com.XXX.tst.frw.common_1.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-18 13:43:55.336
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bundle "com.XXX.tst.frw.common" not found. Possible causes include missing dependencies, too restrictive version ranges, or a non-matching required execution environment.
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.getClassLoader(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:77)
```

#### Working approach 3: Patch Equinox

Patch the `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle to include Luna's `JavaSE-1.8.profile`.

1. Copy file `<LUNA>\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar\JavaSE-1.8.profile` to your target platform bundle pool's `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle.
   (e.g. `<myworkspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar\JavaSE-1.8.profile`)
2. Reference profile in `profile.list` (actually, this seems to be optional):
    add `JavaSE-1.8.profile,\` to      `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar\profile.list`

However, this solution requires hosting your own P2 repository containing the `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle or applying a patch to every workspace's bundle pool.

#### Discussion

Still, there exists the possibility to keep BREE at "JavaSE-1.7" that is compatible with the existing `org.eclipse.osgi` 3.8.2 version.

I am currently aware of two drawbacks:

- Exporting plugins directly from Eclipse via PDE fails if Java 8 syntax is used in the code (e.g. lambda expressions).
- Log contains compiler errors and compiled result is actually of different size compared to a bundle compiled with JavaSE-1.8 BREE.

Presumably, PDE evaluates BREE and sets compiler source level accordingly which then results in "1.7" for Java 8 sources. It is possible that other PDE features (feature export, product export) might exhibit same problem.

Using [Eclipse Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/), it is possible to manually override the javac source level instead of evaluating a bundle's BREE (to select a JDK to compile with). However, also Tycho still matches the given source level vs. BREE and refuses to compile Java 8 code (tested with Tycho 0.22).

Also, approach 2 will most likely not work with PDE's bundle export, at least I am not aware of any possibility to pass VM arguments.

#### Update 29.05.2015

We went with approach 3 and successfully patched our target platform to use Java 8 together with Eclipse 3.8.

As we already maintain our own P2 repository with all 3.8-based Eclipse plugins, we needed to:

- create an updated copy of `org.eclipse.osgi` (needed to strip signing information from bundle as well)
- create a feature patch that patches `org.eclipse.rcp` feature with updated `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle
- publish new 3.8-based P2 repository to be consumed by our workstations and build server.

### Summary

If you maintain your own P2 repository to serve a custom target platform instead of using any Eclipse.org-based update site, it is possible to make Eclipse 3.8 work with Java 8.

References: [Eclipse Bug to support osgi.ee](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323964)

Comment: For legacy products, this is a much better solution than removing the required headers and hoping for the best, or messing around with start up params.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I used the approach 3 as well and it works for our command line PDE build of RCP application based on 3.8.2. However, for me updating the ```profile.list``` file was mandatory.

Comment: One question, we followed the approach 3, but now the PDE build can not compile files that are in java 1.8 source level (f.e. lambda expressions). Seams that PDE build properties javacSource=1.8 and javacTarget=1.8 are ignored completely. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: sorry, we are using Maven Tycho for builds. 
Did you try to set the bundle's BREE (Bundle Required Execution Environment) to 1.8 in MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: We did, does not work. I guess a patch is needed somewhere, but we can not find a place. Any additional ideas?

Comment: Works for us! I have uploaded a patched 3.8.2 osgi lib: https://github.com/hacki11/osgi-3.8.2-jre1.8

Answer (score 4):

An easy fix is to include org.eclipse.equinox.ds (equinox declarative services).  That runtime bundle exports the required osgi.extender and appears to trigger no additional dependencies.

Comment: Here org.eclipse.equinox.ds has a dependency on org.apache.felix.scr. Adding the later fixed the issue.

Comment: had to manually add ```org.eclipse.equinox.event``` besides ```org.eclipse.equinox.ds```

Comment: ```Add Required Plug-ins``` seems to be broken: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494913

Answer (score 3):

I found a configuration that just works, without much work. You select Java 8 in product file, project settings and build path. The important thing is the manifest file. Here you have to select both Java 8 and Java 7. Here also the order is important. Java 8 has to be on top.

I think the reason why this configuration is working is that the compiler selects the first JRE and so can handle the new syntax of Java 8. The eclipse bundles check if one of the entries is the needed Java 7 and are also satisfied.

Comment: Thank you VERY Much for this tip.  I think this may have been the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in the Felix 5.6.10 version that was causing my issue:

> "Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

This is the code that creates the problem.
It is in the constructor of the ExtensionManager

```
String pkgextra =
        "true".equalsIgnoreCase(configProps.getProperty(FelixConstants.USE_PROPERTY_SUBSTITUTION_IN_SYSTEMPACKAGES)) ?
            Util.getPropertyWithSubs(configProps, FelixConstants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA) :
            configProps.getProperty(FelixConstants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA);
    syspkgs = ((pkgextra == null) || (pkgextra.trim().length() == 0))
        ? syspkgs : syspkgs + (pkgextra.trim().startsWith(",") ? pkgextra : "," + pkgextra);
```

changed the last line to:

```
    syspkgs = ((pkgextra == null) || (pkgextra.trim().length() == 0))
        ? syspkgs : syspkgs + (pkgextra.trim().startsWith(",") ? pkgextra.substring(1) : pkgextra);
```

the reason it causes a problem is that a little further on in the constructor we find this code:

```
try
{
    ManifestParser mp = new ManifestParser(
        m_logger, m_configMap, m_systemBundleRevision, m_headerMap);
    List<BundleCapability> caps = aliasSymbolicName(mp.getCapabilities());
    caps.add(buildNativeCapabilites());
    appendCapabilities(caps);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
```

Without the correction the ManifestParser contructor call throws an exception complaining that an exported capability cannot be blank.  That extra comma in the syspkgs made the parser think that some capability was missing.

And once you fail in that try block you don't get your host osgi.ee capabilities added to your framework which means you can't
resolve requests like (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

Just to be clear, this is the specific version I am referring to:

```
org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:5.6.10
```

This issue only occurs if you add some extra system capabilities to your configuration like I did.  So that might explain why some people see this problem and others don't.

I've applied the patch and the filers are once again working.

Answer (score 1):

Real and Quick Solution:

"*I edited the Plug-ins tab on the Run Configuration and checked **org.eclipse.equinox.ds** and clicked 'Add Required Plug-ins'. **THAT FIXED IT**.*"

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494913#c2

Comment: That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in liferay dxp. I had changed liferay workspace and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

I am using Felix 5.6.10

Here's an interesting thing I discovered:
I created two test.jar bundles that contain the following MANIFEST.MF

test1.jar
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Description: bundle used for testing
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.phinneyridge.testbundle
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1
Bundle-Name: testbundle
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Require-Capability: osgi.ee=JavaSE; version="1.8"
Created-By: 1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation)

test2.jar:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Description: bundle used for testing
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.phinneyridge.testbundle
Bundle-Version: 0.0.2
Bundle-Name: testbundle
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version 1.8))"
Created-By: 1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation)

As you can see the two bundles only differ in the Bundle-Version and how the required capability is specified.

The result is:
test1.jar installs just fine
test2.jar produces the missing requirement message when you try to install it.

So there's something about using a filter in the Require-Capability header that doesn't work in my felix osgi framework. Is it not supported, is there something I need to configure to enable filters?  It's clearly not because my framework isn't configured for having the required osgi.ee capability (test1.jar works).

Obviously, that means if I correct the Require-Capability header in the faulting bundles, I got a workaround.  (Not a good solution if you're installing your bundles from an open repository.)