# eclipse RCP 2018-09 + OpenJDK 11 + tycho: how to package an application with the JRE?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, java-11, tycho

Currently I'm using tycho to build and package my eclipse RCP app with java 8 and eclipse 4.8,  ([JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox))
For windows distributions, the tycho build process "copies" the JRE v8 (Oracle) into the distribution package in the`"jre"`directory via an ant task

I'm in the process of upgrading to eclipse RCP 2018-09 and Java 11 (OpenJDK)

2 problems arise:

- OpenJDK 11 does not provide a JRE OOTB. As I do not want to bundle the 300MB of the full JDK in the distribution, is there a way to embed only the equivalent of the JRE for java 11. With tycho itself? by building a specific JRE by using some JDK tools like`"jlint"`on the eclipse-rcp plugins used by my app?
- Tycho and OSGI do not currently fully support Java 11, even with the java 11 plugin from the market place installed. See my [other post on the subject here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607910/eclipse-tycho-java-11-unknown-osgi-execution-environment-javase-11)

I'm curious to find a running example of a tycho `pom.xml` file doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [Adopt OpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)  provides a JRE for Java 11

Example for Java 11 with J9 on Windows x64:
https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=openj9#x64_win