# Eclipse support for Java 10?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is not a duplicate questions. Do we have Eclipse version which supports java 10? Does Oxygen supports Java 10? I have Java 10 installed on my system. I was using Neon but while creating new java projects, I dont see option of selecting java 10 runtime. I get only till Java 8.

This is the error I am getting while selecting JRE 10 in *Installed JRE* preferences dialog:

[image]

**Note:** This question does not refer to the pre-release/BETA Eclipse Oxygen Java 10 support plug-in as in the following question: [*How to set up java 10 in Eclipse Oxygen?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49436841/6505250)

Comment: I tried the duplicate question. But I still dont see JRE 10 while creating new projects. I tried adding it in JAVA_HOME and PATH variables, but still cant see it. In "Installed JRE's" screen, I tried searching for Java 10 JRE by selecting its path, but it gives me error that JRE not found.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse supports Java 10 since [**Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).

See my [video showing the Java 10 support of the Eclipse Java IDE Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGgSLUpRGoc).

Comment: This video is good but is not related to problem I am facing.

Comment: Which version do you have exactly (since Oxygen.1a Java 9 and since Oxygen.3a Java 10 is supported)? If in _File > New > Java Project_ the _JRE: Use an execution environment JRE_ the drop-down list does not contain the item _JavaSE-10_, you have to upgrade Eclipse (_Help > Check for Updates_).

Comment: I have Eclipse Oxygen 3a

Comment: Can you select _JavaSE-10_ in the _New Java Project_ dialog?