# OSGI - Java 8 -> 9 migration (Require-Capability issue)

Tags: java-8, osgi, java-9, bndtools

I am trying to migrate our [bnd(OSGI)](http://bndtools.org/) project from java 8 to 9. After first fail i have prepared basic project. However, I got stuck in problems with java versions capability, exacly like bellow (just a part of them, but all are the same with difference to the java version):

```
! Failed to start bundle org.apache.felix.gogo.command-1.0.2, exception 

Could not resolve module: org.apache.felix.gogo.command [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.felix.service.command; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.felix.service.command; bundle-symbolic-name="org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime"; bundle-version="1.0.0"; version="1.0.0"
       org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime [2]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; version="[1.3.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.apache.felix.gogo.command [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.felix.service.command; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.felix.service.command; bundle-symbolic-name="org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime"; bundle-version="1.0.0"; version="1.0.0"
       org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime [2]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; version="[1.3.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
```

First what I have done was update all dependencies - didn't help though.
I have googled a lot, but with just a few links resulted.
[The one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669940/java-8-missing-required-capability-require-capability-osgi-ee-filter-osg) which was the closest to the problem didn't help thought - I have added following lines, without result:

#### run.bndrun

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-9
Provide-Capability: osgi.ee;osgi.ee="JavaSE";version:List="1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,9"
```

Maybe upgrade my bnd gradle plugin would help, however the version (I am currently using 3.5) mentioned (4.0) at [readme](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md) is not available in `mavenCentral`.

#### My project specification - [basic example repo](https://github.com/Azbesciak/Java9OsgiMigration)

```
Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Bndtools 3.5.0.REL
Java 9.0.4+11
OSGI 6.0
Gradle 4.4
Gradle bnd plugin - 3.5
```

BTW: If you are trying to run project in Intellij, problems can occur - at least we didn't cope to run our main project.

Any help would be appreciated, I will do my best to provide you more info if required.

#### Update

Even when i delete nearly all dependencies [(cleaned branch)](https://github.com/Azbesciak/Java9OsgiMigration/tree/cleaned), after launch  `run.bndrun` I am receiving *only*

```
could not resolve the bundles: [project.main-1.0.0.201804171613 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: project.main [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

]

Failed to start bundle project.main-1.0.0.201804171613, exception Could not resolve module: project.main [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
```

`project.main` is my only bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877329/osgi-java-8-9-migration-require-capability-issue#comment86814142_49881613) we have dedpendency to enroute 2.0, which provides old version of `org.eclipse.osgi`. After manual update to `3.13` problems with `Require-capability` have disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Bnd 4.0 is not yet released. So it is not in maven central currently.

Also, you need to make sure the version of the Felix framework understands Java 9 and can properly provide the Java 9 ee.

Comment: 1) thx for the first answer - I was [this issue](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/2420#issuecomment-381989171) author.:)
2) It can be the reason, however even my own bundle complained about java 8 ... About felix - i have checked `org.apache.felix.gogo` - at least [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime/1.0.12) is quite new... but I couldn't find any info about java 9 support though. Nevertheless, thx for the tip.

Comment: Ok, I have found that Karaf is using felix, even they have recently updated to the [newest version](https://github.com/apache/karaf/commit/9e550d8a654a08eae6ae487578bec8d545b1f6db). Also, Karaf is working on java 9 - [maybe not direct proof](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Using-Karaf-with-Java-9-td4048910.html) but always... To say more, at [main page](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-gogo.html) felix creators says, that ie. Eclipse depends on felix so...

Comment: I am talking about the Felix OSGi framework not the Felix gogo bundles.

Comment: I was wandering "what are you talking to me" because we don't have dependency to `felix osgi` - we are using implementation included in [enroute](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/osgi.enroute.pom.distro/2.0.0) - which uses `org.eclipse.osgi` in version 3.10 - 2015 year. I have updated manualy to [3.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.tycho/org.eclipse.osgi/3.13.0.v20171204-1916) - at least [basic example](https://github.com/Azbesciak/Java9OsgiMigration/tree/mini-no-own-dep) works now.