# Eclipse: an error has occured see log fie configuration

Tags: eclipse-oxygen

While going into the log file this shows up. Please, help to resolve it:

This is what it looks like:

[image: eclipse error]

Error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.css.core 2 0 2019-11-13 17:51:00.216 
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.css.core[878] Unresolved
requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.wst.sse.core;bundle-version="[1.1.1000,1.2.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.wst.sse.core; bundle-version="1.1.1002.v201711071507"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.wst.sse.core[944]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.resources; bundle-version="3.12.0.v20170417-1558"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.resources[143]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)";resolution:="optional"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="3.5.0.v20170509-2149"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ant.core[108]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20170207-1030";singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.runtime[145]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20170207-1454";singleton:="true"
                                   org.eclipse.equinox.common[358]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.contenttype; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.contenttype; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20170207-1037";singleton:="true"
                                   org.eclipse.core.contenttype[130]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences;bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences;bundle-version="3.7.0.v20170126-2132"; singleton:="true"
                                          org.eclipse.equinox.preferences[402]
                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
                                              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20170207-1454";singleton:="true"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.9.3.v20180115-1757";singleton:="true"
                                   org.eclipse.core.jobs[140]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20170207-1454";singleton:="true"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.registry; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.registry; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20170222-1344";singleton:="true"
                                   org.eclipse.equinox.registry[403]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20170207-1454";singleton:="true"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs; resolution:="optional"
                                       -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs; bundle-version="3.9.3.v20180115-1757";bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.core.jobs"; version="0.0.0"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences;bundle-version="3.7.0.v20170126-2132"; singleton:="true"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.app; bundle-version="1.0.0";visibility:="reexport"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.app; bundle-version="1.3.400.v20150715-1528";singleton:="true"
                                   org.eclipse.equinox.app[356]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.registry;bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.registry; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20170222-1344";singleton:="true"
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="3.4.0.v20170113-2056";singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.variables[146]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20170207-1030";singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20170207-1037";singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.expressions[135]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20170207-1030";singleton:="true"   
            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle:org.eclipse.wst.xml.core; bundle-version="[1.1.1100,1.2.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.wst.xml.core; bundle-version="1.1.1101.v201711080222"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.wst.xml.core[970]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.12.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20170207-1030"; singleton:="true"
            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="[3.13.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20170207-1030"; singleton:="true"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 2 0 2019-11-13 17:51:00.217
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa[746]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.persistence; jpa="2.2";
version="[1.1.0,2.3.0)"
    -> Export-Package: javax.persistence; bundle-version="2.2.0.v201708071007"; jpa="2.2";
bundle-symbolic-name="javax.persistence"; version="2.2.0"
       javax.persistence[35]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.maxdb.dbdefinition 2 0
2019-11-13 17:51:00.217 !MESSAGE Could not resolve module:
org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.maxdb.dbdefinition[212]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-11-13 17:51:00.223 
!MESSAGE Application error 
!STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service.Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)     
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)    
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)    
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 & Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669940/java-8-missing-required-capability-require-capability-osgi-ee-filter-osg)

Comment: Is it not somehow similar to this bug -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537751 ?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Older versions of Eclipse don't understand newer versions of Java.